# Какова разница в различных дистрибутивах linux?

Tags: unix, users, linux

Други и подруги, админы юзеры и гости, подскажите советом: юзаю убунту, и на днях задумался - ведь есть много других линухов, например дебиан, подскажите: богата ли разница и стоит ли переходить на другую систему?

Answer (score 1):

Есть такое мнение в узких кругах, что "люди использующие ubuntu думают, что это linux". Шутка шуткой, но есть доля правды :)

Вообще, разница конечно есть, но другое дело увидите ли вы ее, нужна ли она вам. Если вы используете Ubuntu в качестве домашнего desktop, то и не надо метаться. А вот если вы используете в промышлености, то давайте говорить о том в какой сфере и прочее - тогда мы вам подскажем.

Путанно немного, но думаю понятно.

Comment: на самом деле шутка должна звучать несколько иначе: «многие люди наивно полагают, что linux — это не программа, а операционная система».

Answer (score 1):

Если смотреть разницу между Ubuntu и Debian-то разница не особо велика:  Debian сложней в эксплуатации, дистрибутив предполагает, что за компом сидит 'expert', которому проще залезть в конфиг и поправить все ручками, чтобы что-то исправить (настроить) и дебиян более 'спартанский' дистр, здесь за вас делаться ничто не будет, Debian только для пробивных и упорных людей - для 'красноглазых'. Ubuntu наоборот более дружелюбный, он предполагает, что за компом сидит обычный юзер (такого среднего уровня) и поэтому все самые нужные и 'красивые' кнопочки вынесены на самое видное место. Ну и, конечно, есть нюансы в администрировинии этих дистрибутивах.

Если вам так для дома на комп домашний - посмотреть, что такое линкс или просто поиграть - то Ubuntu, а если для работы (администрирование), то несомненно Debian. Хотя если вы человек не пасующий и хотите дома поизучать линукс, то я советую Debian, CentOS...